# Move within a section of Webpage displayed in webview on button click in android?

Tags: javascript, android, html, android-webview

I'm displaying a webpage (html) kept in my assets folder using a `webView`.
My question is how do I **move to a particular section of a webpage on button click** in my application.

There is a HTML page which has many sections on it, and differentiated by various classes in java script code.

So how do I call the class or how do I call the `<a>` tag of html page on my button click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found answer to my question asked by using the following code

```
String baseUrl = "file:///android_asset/abc.html#anchor_tag_name";
WebView wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
wv.loadUrl(baseUrl);
```